# Comma before conditional statement

Tags: commas

The conditional:

> When I copy and paste this answer into my .xml file, it won't read any attributes past the 1st line.

Should I add a comma to the following, before the phrase "when I copy"?

> For some very odd reason when I copy and paste this answer into my .xml file, it won't read any attributes past the 1st line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as a matter of style, you should place a comma after 'For some very odd reason'.  This frames the dependent clause 'when I copy and paste this answer into my .xml file'.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, adding the comma would look more correct to me. I do not have very extensive knowledge of grammar but it seems right to me upon thinking of things I may have written in the past.